# Acces to table rows by ids

Tags: r

I have a very long table containing students from which I want to retrieve a sample of **size = 30** of student in Computer SC. After that, from the given values generated by `sample()`, I want to count the number of students which are at full time.

Remark : I'm fresh user of R and maybe there is functions I have no idea about.

**Table**:

```
id  statut     field       name 
 1  full time  Mecanic     John Mark
 2  full time  Chimestry   Marie Li
 3  Part time  Computer SC Charle MacRay
 ..   ...       ...          ...
```

**Step1:** table contain only Computer SC students

`tableTemp <- table[ which(table$field=='Computer SC']`

**Step2:** sample of size 30

```
sample_length <- 30
v_samp_csc <- sample(nrow(tableTemp ), sample_length , replace = FALSE, prob = NULL)
```

So `v_samp_csc` contain 30 IDs of students(Full time and Part time).

```
 > v_samp_csc
 > 1 5 20 3 4 8 16 5 81 2 65 ...
```

**Question :** How from this IDs, I check if the corresponding student row is at full time in computer SC and count them.

Eg :

```
3  -> Part time  Computer SC Charle MacRay 
58 -> Full time  Computer SC Marie Luise
16 -> Full time  Computer SC Mark moore
```

And it this way, I count the ones which are at Full Time.

Comment: You don't need the `which` at step one : `tableTemp <- table[ table$field=='Computer SC',]`

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Okay to illustrate I just created my own dataset to match what you have.

```
tableTemp <- data.frame(id = 1:100, 
                statut = rep(c("full time", "part time"), 50),
                field = rep("CS", 100),
                name = paste(1:100))



sample_length <- 30
v_samp_csc <- sample(nrow(tableTemp ), sample_length , replace = FALSE, prob = NULL)


v_samp_csc
> 57 20 82 34  9 77 13 96 47 59 19 86 30 31  6 40  1  5 66 75 87 53 44 45  3 17 67 28 52  2
```

First we try to find the index of the students who match the ID we have in v_samp_csc. This will be done with the following code assuming that all ID are distinct:

```
tableTemp$id %in% v_samp_csc
> [1]  TRUE  TRUE  TRUE FALSE  TRUE  TRUE FALSE FALSE  TRUE
> [10] FALSE FALSE FALSE  TRUE FALSE FALSE FALSE  TRUE FALSE
> [19]  TRUE  TRUE FALSE FALSE FALSE FALSE FALSE FALSE FALSE
> ....
```

With this vector we can select the rows which are true, i.e. the sampled students.
    sampStudents <- tableTemp[tableTemp$id %in% v_samp_csc, ]

Now you can just count how many in the new dataset are full time. I noticed that some places in your code it said "full time" and other places it said "Full time". That should of course be taken care of, but for now I would recommend using table to check how many you have of each

```
table(sampStudents$statut)
> full time part time 
>        17        13
```

and if you only have one kind of "full time" you can just count them as you normally would

```
sum(sampStudents$statut == "full time")
> [1] 17
```

**Alternative method**

If you want to speed up your step 2 and 3 (3 here being using your samples to create a new data set) you can use the dplyr package which have a function called sample_n which samples n rows giving us the same result.

```
library(dplyr)
sampStudents <- sample_n(tableTemp, 30)
```

Answer (score 1):

If it is a very big table, you might prefer to store your sampled data.frame, then perform counting on that object:

```
sampleTable <- tableTemp[v_samp_csc,]
sampleFullTime <- sampleTable[sampleTable$statut=='full time',]
```

And since the post title is about accessing by id, you might also do something like this:

```
FullTimeIds <- which(tableTemp$statut=='full time')
tableTemp[intersect(FullTimeIds, v_samp_csc),]
```

Answer (score 1):

This gives a count of the number of students who are full time from a sample of 30 Computer SC students selected at random

```
library(dplyr)
table %>%
  filter(field == 'Computer SC') %>%
  n_sample(30) %>%
  filter(status == 'Full Type') %>%
  summarise(count = n())
```

Slightly more verbose than it could be but that's not a bad thing if you are looking to get into dplyr! You could shorten it to:

```
library(dplyr)
table %>%
  filter(field == 'Computer SC') %>%
  n_sample(30) %>%
  summarise(count = sum(status == 'Full Time))
```